# Loading alternate image in sap.ui.commons.Image

Tags: jquery, sapui5

```
new sap.ui.commons.Image({src: "http://localhost:9090/images/some-image.jpg"});
```

Suppose the above fails if http returns **404 or some error**. The problem is the request is sent by Openui5 internally so it is not possible to intercept from server side either .In that case is there any way to give an alternate **src** such as below:

**redirect url in case of http error -** `src:"http://localhost:8080/images/no-image.png"`

I have been trying the below but its not giving the result:

```
   $(document).ajaxError(function myErrorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   $.ajax({
        // Resend the req
        url: "http://localhost:8080/images/no-image.png"
        }); 
    //imageFile.setSrc("http://localhost:9090/images/no-image.png");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using `formatter function` for the source path received:

```
new sap.ui.commons.Image({src: {path : 'itemImg',formatter: function(itemImg){
        var ImageObject = new Image();
        ImageObject.src = itemImg;
        if(ImageObject.height>0){
        //alert("Ping worked!");
        return itemImg;
        }else {
        //alert("Ping failed :(");
        return "http://localhost:9090/images/no-image.png";
        }
    }}}).addStyleClass("itemImg"),
```

**Alternate solution as suggested by @Qualiture**

```
ImageObject.onload = function() {
    //alert('image loaded successfully.');
    return itemImg;
};
ImageObject.onerror = function(){
  //alert('image loading failed');
  return "http://localhost:9090/images/no-image.png";
};
```

**Note:** Use first solution if you think an image with `height 0` is pointless and better to display a `default image` else the latter is more efficient.

Comment: A slightly better way is to get the `ImageObject.onload` and/or `.onerror` callback functions -- you could potentially have an image of 0 pixels height ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **setAlt** method to set alternative image if not found

Comment: Will the above automatically detect the src has failed and switch to alt because I tried as below but it still fails to show the imagenotavailable string  new sap.ui.commons.Image({src: "http://localhost:9090/images/some-image.jpg",alt: "imagenotavailable"})